# what is the proper way to remove a THREE.ArrowHelper() from a scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm adding some scene clean up to eliminate memory leaks, and I am a bit confused about the proper way to remove an Arrow helper.  (using three.js rev 68)

Assuming I do this to create it:

```
var thisArrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth ));
scene.add(thisArrow);
```

When I try to remove it like this:

```
scene.remove(thisArrow);
```

That works fine.  But I assume that I am getting a memory leak because I have not disposed of the geometry. (I am creating a lot of arrows over time, so this matters)

But when try to dispose of geometry (knowing the Arrow is really a line and a cone) like this:

```
thisArrow.line.geometry.dispose();
thisArrow.cone.geometry.dispose():
```

I get webGL errors:

```
[Warning] WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: no ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER bound ([native code], line 0)
```

Do I also need to dispose of the Arrow itself? What is the proper way to do that.

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: As an alternate approach or work-around, consider creating a pool of arrows and reusing them.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to remove it like this:
>
> ```
> scene.remove(thisArrow);
> ```
>
> That works fine. But I assume that I am getting a memory leak because I have not disposed of the geometry. (I am creating a lot of arrows over time, so this matters)

Doing `scene.remove(thisArrow)` should be all you need to do. `ArrowHelper` shares the same geometry with all the others.